# How to save app and open Window setup in macOS?

Tags: macos, opera

Is there a way to save all open apps, browsing windows and URLS, and windows positions so I can easily re-establish the same window/app state later on?

Answer (score 1):

The Mac ought to do this by default.
Window positions, currently open documents etc should all be restored at relaunch or after a shutdown/reboot.

The only setting I know of that can prevent this is in System Prefs > General > Close windows when quitting an app

[image]

Leave this unchecked for the Mac to remember its last-used settings for apps.

At shutdown or restart, check Reopen windows when logging back in, & everything you had open before shutdown will be restored at login.

[image]

The only time this won't work exactly as expected is if you have any app using more than one Space. All windows will be restored to a single Space after restart.

Comment: Is there a way to save several different windows/apps setups for different work contexts, and load them accordingly?  (It would also be really cool if there was an app that would automatically load a windows/app setup automatically when a space was entered.)

Comment: That would be a whole different question. Maybe https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3133/how-do-i-make-windows-save-their-position-on-screen-after-re-attaching-a-display would help.